# Add subdomain for Vue.js application

Tags: subdomains

I want to add a Vue.js and Laravel application to a subdomain of a WordPress main site. How would I best accomplish that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the Vue/Laravel app is completely separate from the Wordpress site, the easiest and most basic way to achieve this is just to set the subdomain in your webhosting control panel, and point it to the directory on your webserver where you have uploaded the laravel app.

The webserver makes sure that all requests to subdomain.example.com get handled completely independently from the wordpress site.

Comment: Thank you! For now it is completely separate. If I'd want to leverage some of the power of WordPress through the REST API, would that change anything in regards to setting up the subdomain?

Comment: You can call the WordPress rest API completely independently. So the laravel app could be on a subdomain or a completely separate domain, it doesn't make any difference.  You don't need authentication for reading from the REST API, but if you want to write to it you will need to send Auth headers. Sending Auth headers is easiest if the laravel app sends the request via Https. So you need Https on the WordPress site.